# Can't change the mapping to non_analyzed in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a doctype with the following mapping:

```
GET my_index/my_doctype/_mapping
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "my_doctype": {
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "@version": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "prod_id": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "host": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "message": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "path": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "img_path": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "tags": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to change some fields from `analyzed` to `non_analyzed`so I run this request:

```
PUT my_index/_mapping/my_doctype 
{
  "properties": {
    "prod_id": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "img_path": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    }
  }
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Mapper for [img_path] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [img_path] has different [index] values, mapper [img_path] has different [doc_values] values, cannot change from disabled to enabled, mapper [img_path] has different [analyzer], mapper [img_path] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [omit_norms] across all types., mapper [img_path] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_analyzer] across all types., mapper [img_path] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_quote_analyzer] across all types.]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "Mapper for [img_path] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [img_path] has different [index] values, mapper [img_path] has different [doc_values] values, cannot change from disabled to enabled, mapper [img_path] has different [analyzer], mapper [img_path] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [omit_norms] across all types., mapper [img_path] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_analyzer] across all types., mapper [img_path] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_quote_analyzer] across all types.]"
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

How to change the fields "prod_id" and "img_path" to `not_analyzed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the mapping of an existing field. You have two solutions:

1. You can delete your index, recreate it with the proper mapping and re-index your data
2. You can create a `not_analyzed` sub-field and re-index your data

The second solution goes like this:

```
PUT my_index/_mapping/my_doctype 
{
  "properties": {
    "prod_id": {
      "type": "string",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    },
    "img_path": {
      "type": "string",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then you can use `prod_id.raw` and `img_path.raw` after you have reindexed your data.

Comment: Thanks for answering, how to go about re-indexing? I am using logstash to index in the first place.

Comment: The same way, simply re-run your Logstash config and it will populate your new/updated index